# How to route outgoing traffic through another server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, routing

What I'm trying to achieve is to have http(s) requests originating from
machine **A** appear to the target server to be coming from machine **B**.

To illustrate with an example:
Let's say I have two VMs **A** and **B** running Ubuntu and living in the same VPN, machine **A** has public ip `1.1.1.1` and private ip `10.1.0.1`
while machine **B** has public ip `2.2.2.2` and private ip `10.1.0.2`, the VPN's ip range is `10.1.0.0/20`.
Given the above I would like to be able to do this:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1
root@1.1.1.1:~# curl ifconfig.me
2.2.2.2
root@1.1.1.1:~#
```

Note that I'm looking for a solution to route **only outgoing** traffic, I would like the routing of any incoming traffic to not be altered.

I was able to get halfway there by doing the following:

1. on machine **B** enabling ip forwarding with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
2. on machine **B** updating iptables with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/20 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
3. on machine **A** updating routing with `ip route change default via 10.1.0.2`

However this approach breaks all traffic coming *in* directly to `1.1.1.1` including `ssh`, e.g.
to connect to `1.1.1.1` I would now have to do this `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p root@2.2.2.2" root@10.1.0.1`, which is not acceptable for my use case.

It is my understanding that by using `iptables` on machine **A** (rather than `ip route change default ...`) I should be able to route outging traffic through machine **B**, however, so far, I've failed.

One of the things that I've tried is updating the `OUTPUT` chain with `DNAT` on machine **A** (with machine **B** setup as above) but that causes any and all requests to time out.

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1
root@1.1.1.1:~# curl -m 5 ifconfig.me
1.1.1.1
root@1.1.1.1:~# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.2
root@1.1.1.1:~# curl -m 5 ifconfig.me
curl: (28) Failed to connect to ifconfig.me port 80: Connection timed out
```

While I'm not wedded to the `iptables` solution I would like to avoid, if possible, solutions that require the download of non-standard tools.

---

In case it matters, the specific platform I'm using is Digital Ocean, so the VMs are Droplets
and the VPN is what they call Virtual Private Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution for the SSH access with MASQUERADE setup is to add a port forwarding rule on `2.2.2.2`:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 222 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:22
```

Then you can use `ssh -p 222 user@2.2.2.2` to connect to `1.1.1.1`.

If this solution is not enough, then you need a more complex setup.

The MASQUERADE solution above breaks inbound SSH connectivity because of the default route change at `1.1.1.1`.

In this setup incoming packets for the SSH connection come from Internet facing interface. However, `1.1.1.1` sends response packets via `2.2.2.2`, which drops them since they are not associated with a connection.

To work around this, you need to mark the packets belonging to the SSH connection:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m connmark --mark 1 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 1 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

First rule applies packet mark 1 to all packets that are destined to SSH port.

Second rule restores existing connection marks to packet marks to handle routing for both directions.

Third rule saves existing packet mark to connection mark for later connection packets.

Next step is to create a custom routing table for packets related to SSH connections:

Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add the following line:

```
100    ssh
```

Next, add a custom routing table:

```
sudo ip rule add priority 1000 fwmark 0x1 table ssh
```

Then, add a route to the custom routing table:

```
sudo ip route add table ssh 0.0.0.0/0 via <original default route> dev eth0 src 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Since the question was how to route _outgoing_ traffic to another server with this approach you would need to add exception rules for all types of incoming traffic...
But what about reversing the approach: flag all _outgoing_ connections with `iptables -j MARK`, create a custom routing table for that connection with only a default route via server *B* and there use `-j MASQUERADE`?

Comment: Very good point, that approach is better for the use case.